# nodetool status shows nonexisting ip

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a five node Cassandra cluster. When I do `nodetool status keyspace`, the output shows only one IP address—and it's a nonexistent IP. What might be wrong? Seeds shows all IPs on all nodes. Keyspaces and tuples replicate normally.

## Datacenter: datacenter1

```
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  x.x.x.x  301.92 KiB  256          100.0%            c6ea1e24-aa93-429b-b66a-8136db2ef905  rack1
```

Comment: nodetool ring also shows incorrect values

Comment: What you set listen_address and rpc_address in cassandra.yaml?

Comment: Check your seeds configuration, all nodes must have the same seed configuration. Which snitch are you using ?